# TextWatcher makes Typing slow in Edittext(Android)

Tags: android, android-edittext, typing

**The following code i am using for getting status of typing in Text Changes function.....**

```
mEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            try {
                session.typing();
            } catch (OmegleException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, 
                int count, int after) {

        }
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, 
                int before, int count) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: who is session.typing()? what does he do? is his task long or short? does he work on a different thread? do you know how many times it gets called by just typing "123"?  hope these questions will help

Comment: sesion.typing means i am sending the status of typing to other user..This function is working well but when i used here in textwatcher the keypad works slow.. i want when user enter text in edittext this function be work,, in this format working well but problem is that keypad response slow

Comment: yea Madam Ishika, but what i was trying to say was, suppose i type "123" Session.typing will be triggered 3 times or so, that means you will have `Session.typing *3` - now suppose i am hitting up `136 chars`; get where i am going Madam? so try considering running Session.typing on a different thread  or actually have a `int i` that you increment on every typed key-i.e on your TextWatcher listener, and listen to that int and decide to call `Session.typing` on an even number or some calculated approach.

Comment: Thanks i got your point. Yes you are right i am calling session.typing on every text enter.. I just want if use enter text  in edittext the session.typing call only once not on every character .. but how i have to thinks about that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try something like this -guess is a chat app right so -

```
final Random ran = new Random();
mEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, 
            int count, int after) {}
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, 
            int before, int count) {
             if(start %2 ==0 && ran.nextBoolean()){
                 try {
                   session.typing();
                 } catch (OmegleException e) {
                       e.printStackTrace();
                 }
    }
});
```

**Edit**

b4 i do your final request, do you mind runing session.typing on new Thread, like this

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
              try {
                   session.typing();
                 } catch (OmegleException e) {
                       e.printStackTrace();
                 }
              }
           }).start();
```

**Edit 2**

on first letter input

```
mEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, 
            int count, int after) {}
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, 
            int before, int count) {
             if(start ==1){
                 try {
                   session.typing();
                 } catch (OmegleException e) {
                       e.printStackTrace();
                 }
    }
});
```

Comment: Not working , Keyboard still slow.. i just want that if user enter first char or alphabets into edittext then function session.typing call not on every char or alpha entry

Comment: okay i will edit it soon, but can you try runing session.typing on a new Thread? to help free the main UI thread? that is the reason for your lag, do you know much about multi-threading?@IshikaSharma

Comment: Thank you so much creating new thread works well.. i have some other promlems two using thread because i am not familiar with threads..

Comment: hmm.rili? @IshikaSharma what kind of problems?  you can chat about your thread problems [here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90641/elltzextension) or open up a new question here on stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

```
It can be fixed by changing the EditText width to 0dp using weighted widths to 
match/fill the parent.
```

I don't know for sure why this was occurring, however I believe it is because when the width of the EditText is set to wrap content it will adjust/redraw itself so that everything fits. So by making the EditText have a fixed width, this redraw is no longer required.

What does the "0dp" signify for the width? That it should take up all the available space?

yes, it will. The layout_weight tag will do that.

```
 <EditText
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="5"/>
```

For you problem i have one advice for you :

Set your status as typing till user don't press done button on keyboard.

```
editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new EditText.OnEditorActionListener() {
@Override
public boolean onEditorAction(EditText v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
 if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
 //do here your stuff f
 return true;
 }
 return false;
} });
```

Comment: Not right , If i set width of edittext to 0 how the user will see that edittext for entering text ??

Comment: Try this once. you can see typing.

Comment: Not working its not a logic its trick , so please try to do logic not trick thanks

Comment: Not working .. i want to send typing status with post url when i enters text in edittext the textwatcher calls session.typing function  on every text enter which makes slow text entering just like mobile hang